# can not make to work fadein effect on hover of image with css3

Tags: html, css

I have css3 like:

```
.fadeInDown {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown;
    -moz-animation-name: fadeInDown;
    -o-animation-name: fadeInDown;
    animation-name: fadeInDown;
}
img.fadeInDown:hover{
   -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
   -moz-transform-origin: top center;
   -o-transform-origin: top center;
   transform-origin: top center;
   -webkit-animation: fadeInDown 1s ease-in-out;
   -moz-animation: fadeInDown 2s ease-in-out;
   -o-animation: fadeInDown 2s ease-in-out;
   animation: fadeInDown 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Applied to

```
<a  href="#" target="_blank" title="bing">
   <img class="fadeInDown" src="http://www.consortemarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/bing-logo.png" /> 
</a>
```

However is not animating anything, could you please take a look at the [fiddle and help me solve it](http://jsfiddle.net/JXYZn/1/)?

Comment: It works for me (Chrome 26.0.1410.43 m)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you just want the animation to activate on hover?

Comment: yes I want to activate fade animation on hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First some animations will not work well if using `:hover` mostly because it will require you to keep the mouse over the element while it is moving.

rollOut and fadeInDown are better used when activated on page load or when some other element is interacted with.

Second to activate an animation with `:hover` set it up like this:

```
.swing:hover{
   -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
   -moz-transform-origin: top center;
   -o-transform-origin: top center;
   transform-origin: top center;
   -webkit-animation: swing 2s ease-in-out;
   -moz-animation: swing 2s ease-in-out;
   -o-animation: swing 2s ease-in-out;
   animation: swing 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

then just set add the `.swing` class to elements you want to swing.

If you would like all images to swing when hovered:

```
    img:hover{
   -webkit-animation: swing 2s ease-in-out;
   -moz-animation: swing 2s ease-in-out;
   -o-animation: swing 2s ease-in-out;
   animation: swing 2s ease-in-out;
   }
```

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/JXYZn/2/) Happy animating.

Comment: maybe is something wrong but I can  not see the fadeInDown effect... the other 2 effects are displaying fine... what could it be?, even if I keep the mouse over it

Comment: sorry I didn't notice that the -webkit- was missing also I think you have -ms- and -o- mixed up on one of them. Try this http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/JXYZn/3/

Comment: I'm guessing that you've seen Dan Eden's css animation library, but for those having similar issues it may be helpful - http://daneden.me/animate/ -Its very cool for this kind of thing.